# Regex should match linked text and text that is not linked

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
<li><i>(?:<a.*?>)?(.*)(?:<.*?>)?</i></li>
```

Now, this should either match this text:

```
<li><i><a href="hello.htm">Hi there</a></i></li>
```

or without the `<a>` tag, like so:

```
<li><i>42nd Street</i></li>
```

Without the `<a>` tag, the regex works just fine, problem is, with the first example, I get this match:

```
Hi there</a>
```

I've read about ignoring grouping with `(?:regex)` but I do not know why it insists on including the closing `</a>` tag What regex would ignore the closing `</a>` tag so I would only get **Hi there**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(.*)` that you are capturing is greedy, and `(?:<.*?>)?` after it is optional, so the `(.*)` will always include the `</a>`.  To fix this, change the `.*` to `.*?` so it is lazy (match as few characters as possible:

```
<li><i>(?:<a.*?>)?(.*?)(?:<.*?>)?</i></li>
```

[But don't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/505154)

Comment: Thank you. I'm just parsing some _very_ specific HTML that I know wont change.